# simple ajax nothing happens

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I trying to create a small ajax script that add some text into div.
nothing happen, it's killing me.

please help.

**HTML:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE>
    <html>

    <head>
                <script  type="text/javascript" src="ajax.js"></script>
                <script  type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>   
    </head>

    <body onload="process()">
        OK, you made it this far
        <br/>
        <div id="theD">
        </div>

    </body>

    </html>
```

**ajax.js:**

```
    var xmlHttp= createXmlHttpRequestObject();

    function createXmlHttpRequestObject(){
        var xmlHttp;

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)(
            xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        )else{
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
        }

        return xmlHttp;
    }


    function process(){
        alert('hi');

        if (xmlHttp){
            try{
                xmlHttp.open("GET", "ajax.txt", true);
                xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
                xmlHttp.send(null);

            }catch(e){
                alert(e.toString());

            }
        }
    }

    function handleServerResponse(){
        theD = documet.getElementById('theD');

        if (xmlHttp.readyState==1){
            theD.innerHTML += "Status1:server connection established <br/>";

        }else if (xmlHttp.readyState==4){
            if (xmlHttp.status=200){
                try{
                    text=xmlHttp.responseText
                    theD.innerHTML += "Status4:request finish<br/>";
                    theD.innerHTML += text;
            }catch(e){
                alert(e.toString);

            }

            }else{
                alert((xmlHttp.statusText);
            }
        }

    }
```

the ajax.txt contain a simple string.

Comment: If you're using jQuery why in the world are you doing the AJAX in plain JS?

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing happens"?  Do you see any of the alerts?  Have you checked your console for errors?

Comment: `$.get('ajax.txt').done(function(result) { alert(result); }).fail(function() { alert('failed, check console'); console.log(arguments); });`

Comment: TYPO:  theD = **document**.getElementById('theD');

Comment: Look at the error console....

Comment: ohh my god, someone please reduce me some points for my stupidity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is xhr2 if you want more browser support you can extend it.

http://caniuse.com/xhr2

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>ajax</title>
<script>
function ajax(a,b,c){ // Url, Callback, just a placeholder
 c=new XMLHttpRequest;
 c.open('GET',a);
 c.onload=b;
 c.send()
}
function h(){
 document.getElementById('theD').innerText=this.response
}
window.onload=function(){
ajax('ajax.txt',h);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="theD"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

if you have any questions about how this works or how you can extend it just ask

here you have some more info about this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18309057/2450730

you can add ie support

by replacing

```
c=new XMLHttpRequest;
```

with

```
c=new XMLHttpRequest||new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0");
```

and using `onreadystatechange`